# x is not a constructor at nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have three files and the index.js and this is the code with requiring and exporting

index.js:

```
'use strict'
const RemoteService = require('./src/RemoteService.js');
const remoteService = new RemoteService();
```

RemoteService.js:

```
'use strict'
const MoviesService = require('./MoviesService.js');
const AiService = require('./AiService.js');
const aiService = new AiService();
const moviesService = new MoviesService();
```

AiService.js

```
const MoviesService = require('./MoviesService.js');
const RemoteService = require('./RemoteService.js');
const moviesService = new MoviesService();
const remoteService = new RemoteService();
```

MoviesService.js

```
'use strict'
const RemoteService = require('./RemoteService.js');
const remoteService = new RemoteService();
```

I get error
TypeError: RemoteService is not a constructor
at: at Object. (codepath\src\MoviesService.js:9:23)

What am I doing right and is there a better way use these objects?

edited

index.js:

```
'use strict'
const RemoteService = require('./src/RemoteService.js').RemoteService;
const MoviesService = require('./src/RemoteService.js').moviesService;
const AiService = require('./src/RemoteService.js').aiService;
const remoteService = new RemoteService();
```

RemoteService.js:

```
'use strict'
const MoviesService = require('./MoviesService.js').MoviesService;
const AiService = require('./AiService.js').AiService;
const aiService = exports.aiService = new AiService();
const moviesService = exports.moviesService = new MoviesService();
```

AiService.js

```
const MoviesService = require('./MoviesService.js').MoviesService;
const RemoteService = require('./RemoteService.js').RemoteService;
const moviesService = exports.moviesService = new MoviesService();
const remoteService = exports.remoteService = new RemoteService();
```

MoviesService.js

```
'use strict'
const RemoteService = require('./RemoteService.js').RemoteService;
const remoteService = exports.remoteService = new RemoteService();
```

I still get error
TypeError: RemoteService is not a constructor
at: at Object. (codepath\src\MoviesService.js:9:23)

Comment: Your scripts appear to create circular dependencies between them. Be sure that you understand [how Node.js handles supporting them](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Comment: Uh, neither of your files actually exports anything?!

Comment: @JonathanLonowski see the updated code and how can I use the needed references
index use remoteservice
remoteservice uses moviesservice and aiservice
moviesservice uses remoteservice
aiservice uses remoteservice and moviesservice

Comment: It looks like you don't understand how [modules work in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). You need to explicitly export something, not just declare a `const` in the module scope.

Comment: @Bergi That's true I am very new to nodejs I will read the link you sent and if there is a direct solution to make this work it will be very appreciated

Comment: @MoayadAhmad You might want to start simple. Please get your code working in a single file first - for example, you never declare a constructor function anywhere. It's not clear what you actually want to do here, or whether this is just an (incomplete) toy example.